# Built Angular Application only works on First Load

Tags: angular, deployment, build

### Introduction

I have created an Angular application and want to deploy it using `ng build`. After navigating to the `dist` directory and running `live-server`, I encountered some problems. When I initially access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, it displays an error message stating "Cannot GET /new-website/main". Additionally, clicking on the error message redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/new-website/main`, which is not the desired behavior. I aim to have the application accessible at `http://127.0.0.1/main` and eventually replace it with `http://new-website/main`.

### What is my Problem?

The deployment and `ng build` process seem to be causing issues. I suspect that the problem is related to the configuration of `baseHref` or `deployUrl`, but I'm unsure of how to configure them correctly. I have included relevant sections of my code below, and I can provide additional information upon request.

### Goal

My goal is to have the application properly redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/main`.

### My tries so far

- `baseHref='/'` + `ng-build` yields `http://127.0.0.1:8080/new-website` (`/main` cannot be found). But I get errors like `GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/runtime.a43c08078ae396d9.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` (same holds for `baseHref='/main'`)
- `baseHref='./'` + `ng-build` yields `http://127.0.0.1:8080/new-website/main`. However, Images like `/assets/menu-images/About-DE.svg` don't load anymore. The images work when I remove the first `/` from `assets`, but then they won't work for `ng-serve` which is kind of strange.
- `baseHref='/new-website/main'`+ `ng-build` yields `http://127.0.0.1:8080/new-website/main/main` and the images cannot be found again (until I remove the leading `/` of assets, which then again blocks the `ng-serve` from loading the images).

### Additional Information

Project & Folder-Name: `new-website`

Build Options:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/new-website",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "baseHref": "/",
  }
  ...
}
```

RouterModule

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "main",
    component: MainPageComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "privacy",
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: ImprintComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "main",
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "main",
    pathMatch: "full",
  }]
...
```

## Edit: Solution

I discovered that the unusual behavior may be related to the `live-server` itself. When I deployed the website on a real server, it worked without any issues.

Comment: Have you tried base-href='/main'? Or /new-website/main, dependong on where ypu want the app to sit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I've tried that before. Now I added some more information to the question. I hope, that it helps you guys to help me :D. Its so trange why I can't get it working properly...